# Hashmap that keeps original key/value when duplicate key entered

Tags: java, hashmap, key-value, duplicates

Is it possible for a `Hashmap` to keep its original `key/value` pair when a duplicate key is entered?

For example, let's say I have something like this:

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

map.put("username","password1");
map.put("username","password2");
```

I want the original `key/value` pair - username, password1 to be kept and not be overrode by username, password2.

Is this possible? If not, how can I eliminate duplicate entries from being put into the map?

Comment: If you work with Java 8, then use [`Map#putIfAbsent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#putIfAbsent-K-V-) instead of `Map#put`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned, you can use `putIfAbsent` if you use Java 8.

If you are on an older Java version you can use a `ConcurrentHashMap` instead, which has a `putIfAbsent` method.

Of course, you get the additional overhead of thread safety, but if you are not writing an extremely performance sensitive application it should not be a concern.

Comment: what if I use `map.containsKey(key)` to check each entry for a duplicate? How would that compare to using a `ConcurrentHashMap`

Comment: @user2456977 that is also an option if you have single threaded access to the hashmap (which I assume since it is a regular HashMap). However it requires more code to write and is less readable.

Answer (score 2):

If not on Java 8, you have some options.

The most straightforward is the verbose code everywhere

```
Object existingValue = map.get(key);
if(existingValue == null){
    map.put(key,newValue);
}
```

You could have a utility method to do this for you

```
public <T,V> void addToMapIfAbsent(Map<T,V> map, T key, V value){
    V oldValue = map.get(key);
    if(oldValue == null){
       map.put(key,value);
    }
}
```

Or extend a flavor of `Map` and add it there.

```
public class MyMap<T,V> extends HashMap<T,V>{
    public void putIfNotExist(T key, V value){
        V oldValue = get(key);
        if(oldValue == null){
            put(key,value);
        }
    }
}
```

Which allows you to create a `Map` thusly

```
Map<String,String> map = new MyMap<>();
```

EDIT:  Although, to get to the `MyMap` method, of course, you'll need to have the `map` variable declared as that type.  So anywhere you need that, you'll have to take an instance of `MyMap` instead of `Map`.

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#putIfAbsent-K-V-

If you are using Java 8, you can use putIfAbsent.